# Loading Moqui without Demo Data

Tags: moqui, hivemind

I'm new to Moqui/ Hivemind, I have been able to get Hivemind / Moqui up and running with Demo Data, by loading data using

```
java -jar moqui.war load conf=conf/MoquiDevConf.xml
```

however, I need to get Hivemind up without Demo Data (i.e only seed data) and have tried loading data using

```
java -jar moqui.war load types=seed,seed-inInitial,install conf=conf/MoquiDevConf.xml
```

System gets up and running, without Demo Data, but the system does not have any styles. What is the best way to load Seed Data (including default style) without Demo Data. Appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
It seems like the below section in -> https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/framework/Multi-instance+with+Docker has an error instead of seed-initial it calls out as seed-inInitial, I fixed that with the below command for loading seed data and every thing works well

Working Command -> `java -jar moqui.war load types=seed,seed-initial`

Step 6: Check the `moqui.local` instance
You can see if the instance is running from the Instances screen using the 'Check' button in the Instance column. You can also use docker directly to see if the instance is running (with `docker ps`).

To see the logs for the instance use something like `docker logs -f moqui_local`

To resolve the `moqui.local` domain name add it to the system, i.e. in `/etc/hosts`.

Now in your browser you can go to 'http://moqui.local' and if all worked properly you will see a fresh copy of Moqui running with production settings and a database with only seed, seed-ininitial, and install data loaded. Note that there are no users yet in the system so the Login screen will show you a form to create an admin user. This should be done right away after setting up a new instance so that option is disabled.